# Binding pivot table with Laravel Form Builders using checkbox group

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, eloquent

I'd like to bind my checkbox group `Form::checkbox('services[]')` with data from my pivot table but I'm having trouble doing so, I think this is because no key is being returned with `service_id`.

My data model is as follows:

**Business**
**Service**
**Business_Service** *table to store many to many link.*

Blade Template

```
@foreach($service as $service)
{!! Form::checkbox('services[]', $service->id, (in_array($service->id, $selected_services) ? true : false)) !!}
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
$service = Service::all();
$selected_services = Auth::user()->business->services()->get();

return view('signup.step2', compact('service', 'selected_services'));
```

When I return $selected_services I can see the following:

> [{"id":2,"name":"Service
>   1","image":"picture.png","created_at":"2017-03-31
>   00:31:20","updated_at":"2017-03-31
>   00:31:20","pivot":{"business_id":103,"service_id":2}},{"id":3,"name":"Service
>   2","image":"picture.png","created_at":"2017-03-31
>   00:31:23","updated_at":"2017-03-31
>   00:31:23","pivot":{"business_id":103,"service_id":3}}]

I have tried changing `$selected_services` like this:

```
$selected_services = Auth::user()->business->services()->keyBy('service_id');
```

But this only returns one row and doesn't associate a key to the row as expected.

Comment: One minor point with `(in_array($service->id, $selected_services) ? true : false)` is that `in_array` already returns a boolean value, so the ternary is redundant. Use `in_array($service->id, $selected_services)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use inbuilt Laravel functions, then you could use the `Collection::pluck` function.

```
$businessServices = Auth::user()->business->services->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can prepare another array instead of using the collection Eloquent returns but I was hoping there was some built-in function by Laravel I could use.

```
$service = Service::all();
$business_services = Auth::user()->business->services()->get();

$selected_services = [];
foreach ($business_services as $ss) {
    $selected_services[] = $ss->pivot->service_id;
}

return view('signup.step2', compact('service', 'selected_services'));
```